# Greater/Less than or equal to doesn't work in Oracle / SQL Plus

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I'm trying to display a data that is available between certain dates. If I put the exact dates in the date table it works. However when I enter a date that is greater or less than the query doesn't work (no rows selected). Can somebody try and help me direct to the issue? Thanks...

```
Dates
Date_id    StartDate    EndDate
  1        19-FEB-14    31-JUL-14


SELECT FirstName, SecondName
FROM Doctor, Available, Dates, DoctorType
WHERE Available.available = 'YES'
AND Type = '&Type'
AND Dates.StartDate >= '&StartDate'
AND Dates.EndDate <= '&EndDate';
```

Entering 19-FEB-14 and 31-JUL-14 will work. But if I put 20-FEB-14 and 30-JUL-14 for example it doesn't fetch the data.

Comment: Could be that the condition is `Dates.StartDate >= '&StartDate'` but `19-FEB-14` isn't greater or equal than `20-FEB-14` perhaps?

Comment: I did try this, bout without the date format. Stupid silly mistakes -.- Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `date.StartDate` and `dates.EndDate` are both of type `date`, your query is comparing a date to a string.  That means that you'll end up with string comparison semantics (i.e. which string appears first alphabetically) rather than date comparison semantics (i.e. which date appears first on the calendar).  In order to get the right semantics, you'll need to compare dates to dates

```
AND dates.StartDate >= to_date( '&StartDate', 'DD-MON-RR' )
AND dates.EndDate   <= to_date( '&EndDate', 'DD-MON-RR' )
```

assuming that you are expecting both dates to be entered in DD-MON-RR format.

Comment: Yes, they are both date types. Unfortunately still cannot get a row.

Comment: @Devrim - As Joachim pointed out in the comments, your example doesn't make sense.  If you put in a date that is later than the start date or earlier than the end date, your logic is properly excluding it.  The operators are working correctly.  Perhaps you want to reverse the operators (>= rather than <= and <= rather than >=)?